# Adding anchors to jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-tabs

When i click on one of the tabs, it just loads that content.
How do I make it come up with an anchor #index #help etc.
So that after refresh it would be at the same page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').load('content/index.php');

    $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');
    });
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML so we can see if you set up the anchors properly and how theyre named. Also are you expecting to be able to load the pages from `content/' + page + '.php` into the index page? Or use them like regular anchors that just move around the page?

Comment: If you really want anchors you shouldnt even need jQuery. They are actually all HTML based and just clicking on the tab with the proper `href` should take you to where you want to go on the page so Im having trouble understanding exactly what you want

Comment: If I understand your question you want the tab to stay at the same tab if you leave the page. If thats what you want you will need to resort to Cookies to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it well, I think, but to create an anchor you don't need ajax, and I am sure you know that, just assigning an `id` to the part where you want to anchor, and giving it as  `<a href="id">` in the link tag, will cause the url to change and the content to load with your code, and this will maintain your page location after refresh